# ReactJS - Warning: Unknown prop

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I created a simple app to search video using youtube-api, but when I use `npm start` it was not give me any errors but give me the warning `Warning: Unknown prop`onItemSearched`on <searchItem> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
    in searchItem (created by listItem)
    in div (created by listItem)
    in listItem`

Here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var Item = require('./item.jsx');
var searchItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            'queryString' : ''
        };
    },
    handleSearchClicked : function() {
        this.props.onItemSearched(this.state);

        this.setState({
            'queryString' : ''
        });
    },

    handleChangedNameItem : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            'queryString' : e.target.value
        });
    },

    render : function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>
                    <input id="query" type="text" onChange={this.handleChangedNameItem} value={this.state.queryString} placeholder="Search videos..." />
                    <button id="search-button" onClick={this.handleSearchClicked}>Search</button>
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

And this is listItem what i show my results

```
var listItem = React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function() {
        return {
            'results' : []
        };
    },

    handleQuerySearch : function(query) {
        var req = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
            'part': 'snippet',
            'type': 'video',
            'q' : encodeURIComponent(query).replace(/%20/g, "+"),
            'order' : 'viewCount',
        });

        //execute request
        req.execute((res) => {
            var results = res.result;
            this.setState({
                'results' : results.items
            });
        });
    },

    render : function() {
        var listItem = this.state.results.map( item => {
            return(
                <Item title={item.snippet.title} videoid={item.id.videoId} />
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <searchItem onItemSearched={this.handleQuerySearch} />
                <div className="list-item">
                    {listItem}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = listItem;
```

Comment: and what might that warning be? can't do much without knowing what the issue is ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React wants all components to be written in class format. Meaning the names need to be capitalized.

`searchItem` needs to be `SearchItem`

You can also define the props that will be received on search item

```
var SearchItem = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        onItemSearched: React.PropTypes.func
    },
    ....
});
```

Comment: can you explain more specific, i'm a newbie with React, tks u so much, i have change searchItem into SearchItem but its not work :(

Comment: @M.Tae Awesome! the name change (capitalize) is what needed to happen, propTypes specified on the component isn't necessary but its really nice and helps define the component. I'd recommend you keep using that too  :)

Comment: :) i will note that, tks somuch @John